# Authorization header does not work properly when RNDebugger Network Inspect is disabled

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

When toggle network inspect is disabled in RNDebugger, Authorization does not work properly, and I get Unauthorized response from the server. However, when I enable the network inspect in the debugger, it works properly and gives me the correct response. Can anyone help me?

Here is my request when network inspect is disabled:

[image: network inspect disabled]

and here is the same request when network inspect is enabled :

[image: network inspect enabled]

and this is my Axios request:

```
axios.get('https://*******.com/api/v1/profile',{
      headers:{
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Authorization':"<MY_TOKEN>",
      }
    })
        .then(res=>console.log(res))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?